# setting char arrays equal to eachother with isdigit and isalpha

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Im trying to set a char array equal to 2 other arrays depending on if the element in the first array is a number or a letter. The code makes logical sense to me but the output for the 2 other strings after the for loop doesn't correspond to the logic. Is it because of a missing null value somewhere in the other 2 loops or is the code itself invalid? arrayAlpha, arrayNum, and palind are all char arrays set to a length of 30 elements while string length was already determined before the for loop began.

```
for(int k=0; k<=stringLength; k++)
{
    if( isalpha(palind[k])){
        arrayAlpha[k]=palind[k];}
    if ( isdigit(palind[k]))
    {
        arrayNum[k]=palind[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give your expected output and sample input? quite confusing if your problem is with `isalpha`/`isdigit` or checking for palindromes

Comment: @codekaizer yeah sure, for example my string in palind[] will be abc123 so i expect the other 2 string to have abc for the arrayAlpha and 123 for the arrayNum

Comment: what is `palind`? `char*`? or `std::string`? or something else?

Comment: @codekaizer the palind, arrayAlpha, and arrayNum are all char arrays set like "char palind[30];"

Comment: @edmonda7 Just logically, don't you think you need two different subscripts instead of a single `k`?  What if there are 50 alpha characters and 1 digit character in `palin`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but shouldnt it not matter because if the element is a digit it will copy into the new array and ignore the next if statement because isdigit will return false, no?

Comment: @edmonda7 -- What if the only digit is the last character and there are 50 characters?  Your `k` subscript will not be `0`, it will be 49, and you will be writing to `arrayNum[49]` instead of `arrayNum[0]`.  You need two subscripts, one to keep track of where you are in the alpha array, and one to keep track of where you are in the digit array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh you're right i didn't think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input:

```
char palind[30] = "12345abcde";
```

- `arrayAlpha` is garbage.
- `arrayNum` is `"12345"`

However,

```
char palind[30] = "abcde12345";
```

- `arrayAlpha` is `"abcde"`.
- `arrayNum` is garbage.

Thus, `[k]` is the problem when used in your `arrayNum` or `arrayAlpha` which doesn't start with `0`.

Simple change will just be subtracting the length of the other.

```
arrayAlpha[k - strlen(arrayNum)] = palind[k];
arrayNum[k - strlen(arrayAlpha)] = palind[k];
```

since `lengthOfPalind = lengthOfArrayAlpha + lengthOfArrayNum` assuming `palind` only contains letters or numbers.